# Rotation matrix of ligand in vmd

Tags: euler-angles, vmd

I am trying to get rotation matrix of ligand to find Euler angles using VMD software. Using measure inertia command I can get principal axes of rotation. How can I form rotation matrix from normalized principal axes? In one paper I found that some solution related to ordering Eigenvalues of the moment of inertia tensor. Also when I form rotation matrix using principal axes as columns, in some cases I get the matrix with determinant -1 ( it should be 1 for proper rotation matrix). How to deal with such improper rotation matrices to get Euler angles?

Comment: Welcome! Any code snippets?

Comment: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ may also be a place to ask this question if it is more about the science and less about the programming.

Comment: Thanks. I am using measure inertia command in vmd tcl console to get principal axes of inertia and their eigenvalues. I use python code to form Rotation matrix and, then do determinant and other calculations using numpy module.